# VB.Net Date formatting UTC

Tags: vb.net, date, datetime, utc, datetime-parsing

I have a log file that has a date stored in UTC format `"2021-03-29T08:30:29Z"`.
When we are not in British summertime the date stored is wrong, ie it should be 09:30 in the example above.

If I use the following `DateTime.Parse("2021-03-29T08:30:29Z").ToString)` it gives me the correct time but in the wrong format `29/03/2021 09:30:29`

I need to insert this data into a SQL table that expects it to be in the format YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss, can someone help?

Thanks in advance, Darren

Answer (score 0):

Use the ToString Method to format the date as desired, see for example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=net-5.0

But there may be a better way, depending on the database and library you are going to use. If you are using parameterized queries you can just pass your raw variables and let the middleware deal with it. I think that's probably what you should be doing.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I had a problem with this as well a while ago - albeit with SQLite - but it turns out that the UTC date stored is translated to your local time zone when viewed. So its stored as an "absolute" date-time but viewed as a local date-time. That's what it was with my situation in any case, maybe yours as well.